# Since OTA10 upgrade the battery life of my phone is eaten up by "fitbitaccount"

Tags: ubuntu-touch, battery

I can't disable this process which consumes battery life:

```
/usr/bin/online-accounts-ui --socket /run/user/32011/online-accounts-ui/ui-1-com.canonical.scopes.fitbit_fitbitaccount --profile com.canonical.scopes.fitbit_fitbitaccount_1.0.41
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Looks like a serious issue. Why don't you report this bug at Launchpad?

Comment: I don't know yet how to report a bug for phablet. I am looking in ubuntu wiki ...

Comment: Yep, I reported the issue with Bug #1568510.

Answer (score 1):

To quickly stop the mess, I manually removed files about fitbit configuration in phablet accounts:

```
rm ~/.local/share/accounts/applications/com.canonical.scopes.fitbit_fitbit.application
rm ~/.local/share/accounts/providers/com.canonical.scopes.fitbit_fitbitaccount.provider
rm ~/.local/share/accounts/qml-plugins/com.canonical.scopes.fitbit_fitbitaccount
rm ~/.local/share/accounts/services/com.canonical.scopes.fitbit_fitbit.service
```

and finally killing the offending process "/usr/bin/online-accounts-ui" using command kill PID or restarting the phone.

Comment: Also my phone was becoming slow since ota upgrade. After doing that evething became normal.

Comment: Since restored removed files and restarting my device, I can't reproduce again the issue. So it fixed by itself.